# Difference b/w New-AzureRmPolicyDefinition and New-AzPolicyDefinition

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I start learning azure powershell and learn a different commands to create policy definition in powershell. Can someone tell me diff b/w New-AzPolicyDefinition and New-AzureRmPolicyDefinition and when to use which command ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cmdlets perform the same action, except the AzureRm cmdlet is from an older version of the Azure powershell module. They updated the Azure Powershell module in December last year to use the new format "Az". See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-2.1.0

You can run the cmd Enable-AzureRmAlias to allow backwards compatibility, however anything new you are writing I would use the new format.